# Write and read a renamed (or modified) ".aux" file

Tags: auxiliary-files, line-numbering

after compiling (2 times) a `.tex` file with:

```
latex "\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[pagewise]{lineno}\linenumbers}\input{mydocument.tex}"
```

and than compiling again with

```
latex mydocument.tex
```

I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \@LN
```

to remove which, I need to delete the .aux file and compiling again.

To avoid this I figured out to write and read a renamed .aux file for the line-numbering compiling. Is it possible to do that (by command line)?
All suggestions are welcome.

You can try with:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% \usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
%% \linenumbers
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

P.S. How can I insert the compiled file (pdf or dvi) in this page?

*EDIT*: I figured out a possible solution: how if, after compiling, I put the definition of \@LN at the top (or at the right point) of the `.aux` file? My problem is I'm don't know how to find this definition. I looked at lineno.sty but I've not been been found it.

With simple `latex` command the compiler would non complaint about the undefined command and overwrite the aux file. With the lineno package the compiler would simply find a duplicate of the \@NL command definition in the `.aux` file.

Could it works?

Comment: to show the output take a (cropped) screenshot of your pdf viewer and upload a png image

Comment: Why don't you just remove the aux file "from the command line" as part of the compilation process? Something like `/bin/rm -f mydocument.aux && latex ...`

Comment: @Andrew Please, read my comment to egreg answer.

Comment: I don't understand you mean by "I do not want to modify the default emacs compiling setup" because with the `latex "\AtBeginDocument...` you are already doing this. This said, why not expand this line to `latex "\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[pagewise]{lineno}\linenumbers}\makeatletter\def\@LN#1#2{}\makeatother\input{mydocument.tex}"` ?

Comment: @Andrew Ok, I have a default compiling string (actually an emacs command) key-binded to Ctrl-cCtrl-f. I want to use the same key binding for a set of compiling styles. To do that I wrote a set of functions for these styles and a function to toggle the key-binding to these functions (once at time). I don't want to modify the default (internal) emacs function. I need a way to compile the .tex file with the default `tex-file` emacs function aftet compiling with the lineno's `pagewise` option. But it seems not possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please, take a look to my last editing. I think you could help me.

Comment: just use -jobname=zzzz  on the commandline and the aux (and generated pdf) will use that name distinct from the name on your other run

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It would be better to have the same pdf name becouse of the sync with emacs.

Comment: Sorry I give up, you don't want to change the commandline the preamble your emacs setup if you want o try tacking a definition of \@LN to the aux file any definition would presumably do `\def\@LN{}` for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I really thank you anyway. You're one of the best. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it simpler to do the conditional in the document?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifproof
%\prooftrue

\ifproof
  \usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
  \linenumbers
\else
  \makeatletter
  \def\@LN#1#2{}
  \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

When `\prooftrue` is commented, no line numbers are added. Uncomment and you'll get them.

If you really need to do it from the command line, use

```
latex '\expandafter\providecommand\csname @LN\endcsname[2]{}\makeatother\input{mydocument.tex}'
```

for the case when you don't want line numbers.

Comment: Yes it is. But I need to do it by command line. Let me explain my project. I use emacs to format papers for scientific journals. In emacs I have a key binding (C-cC-f) to compile my files. I wrote a function to toggle the key binding behaviour to different kinds of compiling styles (draft, boxed figures... and page numbering). I don't want to modify the tex file. I hope I explained myself enough.

Comment: I really thank you for your effort, but you second solution does not fit yet my needs, because I do not want to modify the default emacs compiling setup (and I don't want to get mad with another option like that). What I really need is to let the linenumbers compiling option make the job.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Well, then you're doomed. ;-) “Botte piena e moglie ubriaca…”

Comment: Really? So I will give up the `pagewise` option. (Without that ones all works fine). Thank you.

Comment: Dear Figaro, "...io son Lindoro, che fido v'adoro..." but I would have preferred "Ecco, ridente in cielo spunta la bella aurora...". No "aurora" this time. ;-)

Comment: Please, take a look to the last editing of the post. I think I can have "la botte piena e la moglie ubriaca".

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Racing condition, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could define `\@LN` in the document preamble, though based not on whether `lineno` is loaded, but simply on whether the `\@LN` macro is defined. The following example illustrates the idea:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% \usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
%% \linenumbers
\makeatletter
\ifx\@LN\undefined
  \def\@LN#1#2{}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I really need to not modify the `.tex` file. I've just explained my needs in a comment to the egreg answer.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to modify something. Either your command line per suggestion by @egreg, or the document source. What's wrong with adding  conditional to the preamble?

Comment: The company I work for doesn't encourage that kind of solutions. Also a command line one will be cleaner and faster. Thank you.

Comment: May be you'd want to have an auxiliary document `proofed.tex` which would contain `\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[pagewise]{lineno}\linenumbers}\input{mydocument.tex}`? After that you build either `proofed.tex` or `mydocument.tex` and have two PDFs, one with line numbers, the other without. The `\@LN`s will go to the `proofed.aux` and won't harm your main `aux`.

Comment: It would be complicate to implement the autors' proofs. :-(